# JSON.parse on an API Response more than once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, parsing

I'm making my first rails app which is a connector to a legacy ecommerce framework to the ship hero warehouse management system.

I'm hitting a wall on a certain issue. I have created a webhook and registered it in the ship hero api. When a shipment goes out it sends data to an endpoint I've created. I received the parameters as so:

Started POST "/ship" for 54.243.50.75 at 2016-07-08 15:22:02 -0400

```js
Processing by WebhooksController#shipment as */*

Parameters: {"{\"test\": \"0\", \"fulfillment\": {\"line_items\": "=>{"{\"id\": \"200CB01-606R\", \"quantity\": 1}"=>{", \"shipping_method\": \"UPS Ground\", \"shipping_carrier\": \"UPS\", \"tracking_number\": \"1Z89ER740392038191\", \"custom_tracking_url\": \"http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?track"=>"yes"}}, "trackNums"=>"1Z89ER740392038191\", \"shipping_address\": {\"address_city\": \"Brooklyn\", \"name\": \"XXX\", \"address1\": \"XXX\", \"address2\": \"APT 2A\", \"address_state\": \"NY\", \"address_country\": \"US\", \"address_zip\": \"11222\"}, \"order_number\": \"WS987182\"}}"}
```

the controller action I have set up is:

```ruby
def shipment
    if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json'
      data = JSON.parse(request.body.read)


       x = JSON.parse(request.body.read)["fulfillment"]["order_number"]
       y = JSON.parse(request.body.read)["fulfillment"]["tracking_number"]
       puts x
       puts y
      render nothing: true
    else
      # application/x-www-form-urlencodedw
      data = params.as_json


      x = JSON.parse(request.body.read)["fulfillment"]["order_number"]
      y = JSON.parse(request.body.read)["fulfillment"]["tracking_number"]
      puts x
      puts y
      render nothing: true
    end
  end
```

this throws an error: JSON::ParserError: A JSON text must at least contain two octets! But if I remove one of the x or y variables from each conditional it parses the correct value i am looking for ( the tracking number or order number). So as long as I only parse 1 value it works. I don't understand why. [Here](http://docs.shipheropublic.apiary.io/#reference/webhooks/shipment-update-webhook-url/shipment-update-webhook-url) is the link to the ship hero apiary for the Webhook Shipment URL documentation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to parse request body yourself. What you need has already been prepared by Rails, and you can access them through `params`

```
x = params["fulfillment"]["order_number"]
y = params["fulfillment"]["tracking_number"]
```

P.S. `request.body` is an IO thus it can only be read once.

Comment: I am actually getting an error with this. NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/webhooks_controller.rb:61:in `shipment'

Comment: If the error was raised in the above code, then you should check whether `params["fulfillment"]` is `nil`, or you can leverage [strong parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters). `params.require(:fulfillment)`, which will send a *422 Unprocessable Entity* response immediately if "fulfillment" is missing.